# basic javascript if-else function not working?

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement, console

javascript file:

```
var danger = 1;
var safe = 2;

function stepLeft() {
    if (danger == 1) {
        alert("STOP!")
    } else {
        alert("START!")
    }
}
```

Nothing is happening when I try this. No error message in console either. (the script is linked properly in html).

Comment: Just call the Js function,

    stepLeft();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only defined the function, but you actually never ran it. Try adding

```
stepLeft();
```

After the definition to execute it.